# TIBCO AMS vs. Lighstreamer

Tags: ajax

What's the difference between TIBCO AMS and Lightstreamer? Aren't they the same? Has TIBCO acquired Lightstreamer? Which one will you prefer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record.
I got this from a Lightstreamer rep in email: Tibco have an OEM agreement with us and sell the Lightstreamer technology as "AMS" along with the support directly according to their license model